Checking for spelling Latin for tattoo
Can anyone control on spelling for my tattoo the following text translate to Latin:
English: Live your life and enjoy every day
Netherlands: Leef je leven en geniet van elke dag
Translate to Latin:
Vive vitam tuam et omni die fruere

Not posting this as an answer since the question is just about spelling, but: quotidie is an adverb, so the Latin means "enjoy every day" not in the sense that the day is what you should enjoy, but that every day, you should enjoy (something unspecified). (I think the Dutch would be geniet elke dag, though my Dutch is shaky.)

The spelling is correct.
What one might remark is that quotidie is an alternative spelling for cotidie (or cottidie), and one that, over the centuries, has occasionally been disparaged. Quintilian (who lived ca. AD 35–100) already was unenthusiastic about this spelling, though it is remarkable that he brought it up as a recommendation made by some people (it is not clear by whom, it seems to be a vague “they”), supposedly to make explicit that it is an abbreviated form of quot diebus (Inst. 1, 7):

Similiter putaverunt illa quoque servanda discrimina [⋯] Frigidiora his alia, ut "quidquid" c quartam haberet ne interrogare bis videremur, et "quotidie" non "cotidie", ut sit quot diebus: verum haec iam etiam inter ipsas ineptias evanuerunt.
Similarly, they thought the following distinctions should be made [there follow some examples] There are other, less inspired ideas, such as writing "quidquid" with a c in the fourth position, so that it does not look like we are asking twice, and writing "quotidie" instead of "cotidie," so that it is "quot diebus"; but these recommendations are not made anymore, even in a flippant way.

I would infer that cotidie was the spelling that corresponded to the pronunciation, and quotidie a smart-alecky etymological spelling.
That said, Quintilian was certainly wrong about quotidie vanishing – here we are very nearly 2000 years later, and quotidie is evidently still with us, so I'd say feel free to spell it like that if you prefer it.
Note that, apart from the spelling, the translation is not correct: quotidie fruere means “enjoy daily” – “enjoy every day” would be quoque die fruere.

Thank you for answering. I want to use it for a tattoo. This it would be better:   Vive vitam tuam et quoque die fruere     Or can also:   Vive vitam tuam et frui cotidie
